# Introduction to $L^2$ space. Equivalence class concept

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, equivalence-relations, almost-everywhere

> Given a probability space $\left(\Omega\text{, }\mathcal{F}\text{, }\mathbb{P}\right)$, let $L^2$ denote all (equivalence classes for a.s. equality of) random variables $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}\{X^2\}<\infty$. We henceforth identify all random variables $X$, $Y$ in $L^2$ that are equal a.s. and consider them to be representatives of the same random variable. This has the consequence that if $E\{X^2\}=0$, we can conclude that $X=0$ (and not only that $X=0$ a.s.).

I am not sure I am correctly interpreting the above-quoted statements.

What I understand is that, since $E\{X^2\}=0$, given that $\text{Var}(X)=E\{X^2\}-E\{X\}^2\geq0$, it must hold that $E\{X\}=0$. So, at this point one can say that, since $E\{X\}=0$ and $\text{Var}(X)=0$, $X$ follows a degenerate distribution, that is that $X=0$ a.s..
Now, pretending that what I have said so far is ok, does the statement "we can conclude that $X=0$ **(and not only that $X=0$ a.s.)**" follow from the fact that (see part in bold) "$L^2$ denotes all (**equivalence classes for a.s. equality of**) random variables $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}\{X^2\}<\infty$"?

If my reasoning was totally wrong, could you please clarify the meaning of the paragraph above?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually way more fundamental and only a matter of perspective. $X = 0$ in $L^2$ has a different meaning than $X = 0$ in the space of random variables.
Before introducing $L^2$ we knew that $E\lbrace X^2 \rbrace = 0 \iff X = 0$ a.s..
Now things have changed as $L^2$ only contains equivalence classes (i.e. sets) and is a completely different Vector space than the space of random variables. 
Now, what does it mean for $[X] \in L^2$ to be $0 \in L^2$ ($[X]$ denotes the equivalence class of some random variable $X$)? It means that $Y = 0$ a.s. for all $Y \in [X]$ by definition of $L^2$. So: The zero element in $L^2$ is just not a random variable anymore, it's a completely different object.
**Remark:** We can still write down integrals of equivalence classes as the integral of an arbitrary representant, because every random variable in an equivalence class has the same integral (because they only differ on sets with measure zero). Often the goal of this new perspective is to introduce a norm $\lVert X \rVert_{L^2} := \sqrt{E\lbrace X^2 \rbrace}$ on $L^2$ which requires $\lVert x \rVert_{L^2} = 0 \iff x = 0$ in $L^2$.

This is the concept of so called quotient spaces about which you can learn in a good Linear Algebra book.

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot. I would like to ask you something more (sorry for my ignorance). You said "what does it mean for $[X]\in L^2$ to be $0\in L^2$ ($[X]$ denotes the equivalence class of some random variable $X$)? It means that $Y=0$ a.s. for all $Y\in [X]$ by definition of $L^2$". **First**: what do you mean by...  $[X]\in L^2$ *is* $0\in L^2$? You mean.."pretend that $0$ belongs to the equivalence class of random variable $X$"? *[continue]*

Comment: *[continue]* **Second**: "So: The zero element in $L^2$ is just not a random variable anymore, it's a completely different object". In which sense $0$ is a different object? How does this statement prove what I need to understand, i.e. that $E\{X^2\}=0\iff X=0$ and not simply that $E\{X^2\}=0\iff X=0 \text{ a.s.}$?

Comment: Just to notify @Shaqinho

Comment: (1/2): Your question is basically about vector space theory. I hope we agree, that $L^2$ is a vector space. A vector space has a zero element, i.e. an element $0 \in L^2$ with $x + 0 = x$ for all $x \in L^2$. Now remember that x is a set of function, not a function. Let's consider some  random variable $X$, i.e. $L^2 \ni [X] = \lbrace \text{ all random variables }Y\text{ with }X = Y a.s. \rbrace$ just to recall the definition. Now the Addition on $L^2$ is defined as $[X] + [Y] := [X+Y]$. The addition in the bracket is the  addition on the space of random variables. Now, let's take a look at

Comment: (2/2): $L^2 \ni [0] = \lbrace \text{ all random variables }Y\text{ with }0 = Y a.s. \rbrace$. Then for all $[X] \in L^2$ the relation $[X] + [0] = [X+0] = \lbrace \text{ all random variables }Y\text{ with }\underbrace{X + 0}_{=X} = Y a.s. \rbrace = [X]$ holds. This means that $[0]$ is the zero element in $L^2$. Always remember: $L^2$ contains sets of random variables. Now: We know that for a random variable X we have $E\lbrace X^2 \rbrace = 0 \iff X = 0$ a.s. But the set random variables with $X = 0$ a.s. is the zero element in $L^2$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now it's clearer! I have just a very basic and not complete knowledge of Linear Algebra. Could the book "Linear Algebra and its Applications" by Strang be a good reference so as to better focus on vector spaces? @Shaqinho

Comment: I'm glad I that I could help you. Strang's book is great but ist focus is on application. If you want to learn about vector spaces and their theoretical properties (which imo every mathematician should know) this book might not suit you that well. I have just taken a look at "Linear Algebra" by Nair and Singh and it is very similar to the book that i read when studying Linear Algebra (Fischer - Lineare Algebra; I'm german). It covers Quotient Spaces in section 1.8 and my not be that easy for beginners but it's quite complete. Strang's book is a classic though and Always worth reading.

Comment: If you read about quotient spaces you will understand this construction: If $Z$ is the vector space of random variables with $E\lbrace X^2 \rbrace < \infty$ then $L^2 = Z/N$ holds if $N := \lbrace X \in Z:~ X = 0\text{ a.s.} \rbrace$.